# After each comma restrict to six characters in android

Tags: java, android

i need to restrict six characters after comma in edittext of android and i should able to add characters bfor comma...

ie 3000,898989,898345...3000 can be 30000 or 300000...infinite but characters after comma should be fixed to six...

after each comma only six character canbe typed in edit text...

how to go about it?

i have tried with the following

```
public class CustomEditTextActivity extends Activity {

EditText et;
Context cn=null;
int commacount=0;
String aftercomma;
boolean  flag=false;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                             cn=this;
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    // Listener for edit text text change
    et.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);


}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside afterTextChanged() method");



    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

        System.out.println("Inside beforeTextChanged() method");


    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
                      flag=false;
        commacount=0;
        String getDataFromeditxt = s.toString();
                int comma = getDataFromeditxt.indexOf(',');
                String bforcomma = getDataFromeditxt;
                if (comma != -1)
                {
                    bforcomma = getDataFromeditxt.substring(0, comma);
                }



                               // Checking for , in the data and setting its position
                                for (int i = 0; i < getDataFromeditxt.length(); i++) {
                                    char c = getDataFromeditxt.charAt(i);
                                     if(flag){
                                      aftercomma=new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
                                         int maxLength =bforcomma.length() +6+commacount;
                                        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
                                        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
                                        et.setFilters(FilterArray);
                                        System.out.println(aftercomma);

                                    }
                                    if (c == ',') {
                                        commacount=commacount+1 ;
                                         flag=true;
                                    }

                                }

    }

};
```

}

the problem in above code is that once maxlength is set i can't type anyting...any solution??

Comment: This might not be the actual source of the problem, but `bforcomma.length() +6+commacount;` would allow you to add at most 6 (non-comma) characters after the first comma, even if more commas are added. Shouldn't that be `bforcomma.length() + (6 + 1) * commacount`?

Comment: sorry Actually this is my code which i had written...i took condition what happens when one comma comes..i knw this is not right...i just posted wht i did..in this condition once maxlength is set i cant add data bfor comma

Comment: I am not sure if I get the problem. Do you (1) want to verify if the string has commas spaced by six characters after first comma appears, or (2) want to auto-insert commas after first comma is added?

Comment: both are wrong after each comma i should make user to type  only 6characters.but bfor FIRST comma he can type characters without any restriction

Answer (score 0):

```
Use pattern matching in java. Replace str with text from editext.
String result="";
String str= "300066666666666666666,898989,898345,000000,111111,333333";//editext.getText().toString();
String regex ="(^[0-9]+)([,]+[0-9]{6})+$";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
if (matcher.find( ))
{
result = matcher.group();  
System.out.println("number="+result);            
}
else
{
     System.out.println("no match found"); 
}
output
number=300066666666666666666,898989,898345,000000,111111,333333
```